# Transaction not committing

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, transactions

In my SSMS I have checked the "SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS" because I do not want to do any commits automatically. When I run the below code, the transaction still does not get committed. Am I missing something else?

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
  BEGIN TRY
    EXECUTE prModifyOrAdd '73891821'
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
  END TRY
  BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT 'ERROR'
  END CATCH
```

Here is the design of the procedure:

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[prModifyOrAdd] @id varchar(50) 
 as
 DECLARE @outMessage varchar(25)
 update INDV834
 set FILENAME= @id+'.txt'
 where SUBSCRIBER_ID=@id

 if (select distinct filename from INDV834 where SUBSCRIBER_ID=@id)=      (@id+'.txt')
   BEGIN
    SET @outMessage = 'Completed: ' + (@id+'.txt')
    select @outMessage
   END
 else
   BEGIN
    SET @outMessage = 'Errored'
    select @outMessage
   END
```

Answer (score 0):

If you start a transaction explicitly, as you did, the set implict is ignored. What is happening in the stored procedure? Does it have its own error handling and   is it handling the error before you see it?

Many users wrap their rollback with a @@trancount as so:

begin catch

if @@trancount>0

begin

```
rollback
```

end

end

Comment: The stored procedure updates a table and returns a message if it was successful or if it wasn't. The return message does say that the process was successful but when I close the SQL worksheet and do a query to verify, the record is not updated.

Answer (score 0):

There are few reasons why you don't see the "data committed":

0) If you have checked `IMPLICT_TRANSACTION` option in SSMS then after `BEGIN TRANSACTION` will be two active transactions. This means that you need to `COMMIT` statements.

See also [Nesting transactions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189336(v=sql.105).aspx)

Note: At this point (`IMPLICT_TRANSACTION ON` + `BEGIN TRANSACTION` + **just one** `COMMIT`), concurrent connections will be blocked because a transaction will be active (`SELECT @@TRANCOUNT`).  *And, if you close SSMS window, current [implicit] transaction will be automatically cancelled (ROLLBACK) => you will loose any modifications made by stored procedure.*

My recommendation is to avoid `IMPLICT_TRANSACTION`. *So, please uncheck this option.*

1) `INSERT` / `UPDATE` / `DELETE` / `MERGE` statements from `dbo.prModifyOrAdd` could afftect 0 rows. For example, an `UPDATE` statement may have `WHERE` clause but conditions from `WHERE` are `false`, so 0 rows are updated.

2) Target tables have `INSTEAD OF` triggers that do nothing or have some *bugs*.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, Col1 INT)
GO
INSERT dbo.MyTable VALUES (11)
INSERT dbo.MyTable VALUES (22)
GO

CREATE TRIGGER trgTrivialInsteadOfTrigger 
ON dbo.MyTable
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    PRINT 'trgTrivialInsteadOfTrigger activated'
END;
GO

UPDATE   dbo.MyTable
SET     Col1 = Col1 * 10;
SELECT * FROM dbo.MyTable;
GO
/*
-- Col1 isn't updated 11 -> 110 ...
ID          Col1
----------- -----------
1           11
2           22

(2 row(s) affected)
*/
```

3) You source code is executed in the context of another transaction that execute at the end `ROLLBACK` (see nesting transactions):

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

... your source code ...

ROLLBACK <-- this statement will cancel all modifications
```

Example:

```
DROP TRIGGER dbo.trgTrivialInsteadOfTrigger -- <-- see 2)
GO

BEGIN TRANSACTION
    BEGIN TRANSACTION 
        UPDATE   dbo.MyTable
        SET     Col1 = Col1 * 10;
    COMMIT
ROLLBACK
SELECT * FROM dbo.MyTable;
/*
ID          Col1
----------- -----------
1           11
2           22

(2 row(s) affected)
*/
```